# Access default value attribute from inside EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a custom editor template that converts a simple text box into a numeric box (for type number). However I am trying to pull over the default value from the model as defined in the `DefaultValue` attribute

In the model I have

```
[DisplayName("Initial Token Count")]
[DataType("Number")]
[Required]
[DefaultValue(5)]
public int InitialTokenCount { get; set; }
```

The EditorTemplate I have

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line", type = "number" })
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@Html.NameFor(c => c)").kendoNumericTextBox({ decimals: 0, format: "#"});
    });
</script>
```

Now when the view renders if there is no value defined then it defaults to `0` but I would like it to default to `5` as defned in the `DefaultValue(5)`

Am I missing some call to make that happen?

Comment: If you want to bind model property and corresponding attributes in your view, your should use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.TextBox`

Comment: @WeTTTT I Don't believe I can do that since this is a EditorTemplate and not a generic view (thus the model is always dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to achieve this:

```
@{
    object value;
    if(Model == null)
    {
        value = ((System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute)
                            ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName).
                            GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute), false)[0]).Value;
    }
    else
    {
        value = ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", @value, new { @class = "text-box single-line", type="number"})
```

EDIT: Changed it a bit so it works with existing model value.